# Adjective meaning 'using creative prose/being poetic'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Here's the context, somebody has written this:

> Quiet workplace... then - all of a sudden, a loud voice; complaints,
>   criticism, aggressiveness. Everyone's attention is drawn to an
>   argument - and sometimes the spotlight is on the person being publicly
>   executed.

And I want to say something like, 'That paragraph is a bit melodramtic and [uses creative writing for the sake of being entertaining to read], could you edit it to tell us what actually happened?'.

Comment: You could use "bombastic", "verbose", "flowery" or even "pompous".

Comment: [purple prose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_prose) *is so extravagant, ornate, or flowery as to break the flow and draw excessive attention to itself.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps **[theatrical](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/theatrical)**

> characteristic of the theater; dramatic; esp. (in disparagement), melodramatic, histrionic, showy, or affected